# What is the secure solution for correcting mass assignment vulnerabilities in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, brakeman

I'm working on securing an existing Rails 3 project. Running brakeman, I'm receiving this warning for many model classes: "Potentially dangerous attribute available for mass assignment: :example_id"

All of the warnings are on _id columns.

The models currently look like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :commentable_id, :content, :user_id
```

Along with the main question, if the _id columns are removed to satisfy the warnings, what is the proper way to set these fields then?

Answer (score 1):

In `rails` it's always better to use `Active Record` association `API`.

In your case it's safer and cooler to:

```
@commentable = Commentable.take
@commentable.comments.build attribute: 'value', ...
# or
@commentable.comments.create attribute: 'value', ...
```

Rather than:

```
Comment.new commentable_id: @commentable.id, attribute: 'value', ...
```

Therefore if you'll stick with best practicies you won't need to whitelist `commentable_id` or any other `_id`.

You should also consider currently recommended mass-assignment protection solution — [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters):

— [*«How to Upgrade to Strong Parameters in Rails»*](http://carreno.me/articles/how-to-upgrade-to-strong-parameters-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

if you use it, per default ALL parameters are forbidden. If any controller should use some parameters, you need explicit to permit them.

Let's imagine you have Users and Entries. If a someone is going to update his entry and sends additionally an `user_id` parameter, he could re-assign the records user which is really bad. 
Since `strong_parameters` blacklists all parameters you allow the controller to accept only `entry.name`, `entry.details` and `entry.tags` (or whatever). Even is the `entry.user_id` is sent, it will be **ignored**!

You might wanta to take a further look :
https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Comment: This does not answer the question, you need to specify the details of the answer and how to solve it instead of just referencing a link .

Comment: so then edit my answer please or can i post it as a comment?

Comment: so is this better now?

Comment: I didn't realize strong parameters could be added to Rails 3. I've been using them in 4. But the second part of my question still applies. Sometimes you need to capture _id fields from forms, so if not mass assignment, then what?

Comment: if you need to capture the _id fields, then its okay to allow those attributes. if a user is able to select some _id fields in a form, then its not a problem and no security issue